# How to get the line index in a row from CSV imported into Python?

Tags: python, csv

[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmfII.png)

Basically, I want to be able to get the vertical index position of the maximum number from an imported CSV. I have been able to grab the maximum number from the CSV which is 188 and represented by 'maxTemp'. I need the vertical position of the number from the CSV, I know how you get what column it is in but how do I get the vertical index position of it?

I hope this makes sense.

```
`with open('CSV_load.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    names = []
    surnames = []
    marks = []
    maxTemp=[]
    for row in readCSV:
        maxTemp.append(int(row[2]))
        name = row[0]
        surname = row[1]
        mark = row[2]

        print(name, surname, mark)
    print("\n")
    print("The highest mark is:", (max(maxTemp)))
    print("\n")`
```

I cannot figure out how to get the vertical index position from the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate()` + `max()` to get row with highest value. For example:

```py
import csv

with open("CSV_load.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    line, row_with_highest_temp = max(
        enumerate(readCSV, 1), key=lambda row: int(row[1][2])
    )
    print("Highest Temp is", row_with_highest_temp[2], "on line", line)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I used the code you provided and it works great! But now that I know it is in position 12 how am I able to print out the value position 12 from a CSV? Like because I need to match that number 188 up to a name which is in another row, so how do I print position 12 from the other CSV row?

Comment: @BrandonMiller I don't understand, can you be more specific? What does *"how do I print position 12 from the other CSV row?"* mean?

Comment: Please see this image link for a complete explanation. https://ibb.co/NShRH5N

Comment: Did you see the image?